# If $N\lhd H×K$ then $N$ is abelian or $N$ intersects one of $H$ or $K$ nontrivially

Tags: group-theory

I am thinking on this problem:

> If $N\lhd H×K$ then either $N$ is abelian or $N$ intersects one of $H$ or $K$ nontrivially.

I assume; $N$ is not abelian so, there is $(n,n')$ and $(m,m')$ in $N$ such that $([n,m],[n',m'])\neq 1$. But I can’t go further. Hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited those extra $N$s into $K$s, but I'll let OP deal with the rest of anon's comment.

Comment: I assume that the $N$ which appears in the direct product is supposed to be $K$.  Also, I adopt the usual convention of identifying $H$ with $H \times 1,$ etc.. Hint: If $N \cap H =1,$ then $[N,H] =1$ (that is, $N$ and $H$ centralize each other) and similarly for $K$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Gerry edited it correctly. It was my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember: in general, $\,N\lhd G\Longrightarrow [G,N]\leq N$ , so in your case:
$$N\lhd H\times K\Longleftrightarrow [H\times K:N]\leq N\Longrightarrow \,\,\text{in particular}\,\,[H:N]\,,\,[K:N]\leq N$$

where we identify $\,H\cong H\times 1\,\,,\,K\cong 1\times K\,$

Now suppose $\,N\,$ intersects both $\,H\,,\,K\,$ trivially, so $\,[H,N]\subset H\cap N =1\,$ and etc...can you take it from here?

Comment: I say, since $[N,H]=1$ so if $(n,n')$ and $(m,m')$ be in $N$ then $nmn^{-1}m^{-1}=1$. We have the last identity because we can regard $m$ as an element in $H$. The rest is similar for $N$ and $K$. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: Lo @BabakSorouh, I meant what I wrote. Why should I write the same thing twice?

Comment: Indeed, @BabakSorouh: so $\,N\,$ commutes with both $\,H\,,\,K\,$, so...?

Comment: So, $N$ is an abelian subgroup. Thanks Don.

Comment: Excuse me. Does $[G, N]$ mean the normalizer of $N$ in $G$?

Comment: @bfhaha No, it is their commutator: $$[G,N]:=\langle\,[g,n]\;|\;g\in G,\,n\in N\,\rangle $$

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution which avoids using the notation $[-,-]$. 
It is the same as DonAntonio's solution and Geoff Robinson's hint essentially.

**Lemma.** If $A\lhd G, B\lhd G, A\cap B=\{e\}$, then $ab=ba$ for all $a\in A, b\in B$.

Suppose that $N\cap H=\{e\}=N\cap K$. 
Note that $H\lhd G, K\lhd G$. Then by the lemma, $nh=hn$ and $nk=kn$ for any $n\in N, h\in H, k\in K$.
It follows that $N\subseteq Z(G)$ because $G=H\times K$.

This question also appears in Hungerford's *Algebra* (Exercise I.8.7).